# How to fix R leaking memory (hogging memory with empty environment)

Tags: r, memory-management, memory-leaks

When I clear the Global environment in R, and then invoke garbage collection, R continues to hog memory (see code below). Is there a way to clean up memory "even more" without restarting R?

```
> rm(list = ls())
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)   max used    (Mb)
Ncells 1352699 72.3    2419890  129.3    3886542   207.6
Vcells 4231877 32.3  910657255 6947.8 1412741750 10778.4
> unloadlibs() # wrapper to remove all packages in 'sessionInfo()$otherPkgs'
[1] "Unloaded packages:"
 [1] "magrittr"   "zoo"        "reshape"    "stringi"    "openxlsx"   "lubridate"  "dtplyr"     "dplyr"      "RODBC"     
[11] "data.table"
> gc()
          used (Mb) gc trigger   (Mb)   max used    (Mb)
Ncells 1349320 72.1    2419890  129.3    3886542   207.6
Vcells 4230328 32.3  728525804 5558.3 1412741750 10778.4
```

In this case, there is still more than 700mb of memory used after cleaning everything.

Is it a known issue, or am I doing something wrong (in this case, what is it)? What may be the culprit and faulty code that may result in this? I already :

- Dropped dplyr usage,
- Try to use data.table in any case possible,
- And use copy() in the code when I am afraid that data.table references will somehow confuse garbage collection (not sure how a single reference to a data.table will behave).

Thanks for your inputs.

Additional info:

```
> R.version

platform       x86_64-w64-mingw32          
arch           x86_64                      
os             mingw32                     
system         x86_64, mingw32             
status                                     
major          3                           
minor          4.3                         
year           2017                        
month          11                          
day            30                          
svn rev        73796                       
language       R                           
version.string R version 3.4.3 (2017-11-30)
nickname       Kite-Eating Tree
```

Comment: What is Ctrl+Shift+F10 supposed to do? This doesn’t mean anything in the context of pure R. Anyway, to answer your question it’s kind of necessary to know what you did in the R session *before* the `gc()` call.

Comment: @KonradRudolph It's RStudio's keyboard shortcut to restart R. I have added the rstudio tag.

Comment: @RuiBarradas Thanks. However, with your permission I’ll remove that tag again and fix the text, since the question doesn’t seem to be specific to RStudio.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Ok, it seems to be an R question, not a RStudio one.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: A lot of data wrangling actually- merging, subsetting rows and columns. It is indeed duplicate (I could not find that "original" topic on my own), I think the phenomenon is indeed related to the lack of memory compaction of R.